# SQL Server timeout while restoring databases with SMO

Tags: sql-server, smo

I have a .NET application where I restore a number of databases using SMO. The timeout setting in the connection string is set to 0 (unlimited). Most databases restore fine, except one databases that sometimes times out on the restore. The size of it approaches 3 GB. Are there any workarounds for this problem? Is there a setting I am missing.
I am using DatabaseRestore object to restore the database.
Thanks!

Comment: not for nothing, but is it something you cannot restore using SSMS?

Comment: It's done as part of our automated build. So doing it manually through SSMS is a no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two timeout settings for SMO - one is the ConnectionTimeOut settings, and the other is the StatementTimeOut setting - you need to make sure you are setting the right one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/b4000547-7a48-4bda-9a68-ac646259e7d2/

This is another question with a specific issue that resolved their problem: [SMO ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout setting is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784247/smo-connectioncontext-statementtimeout-setting-is-ignored)

Hope this helps...

Also, there is a poweshell script that 'supposedly' works well for large databases.. http://devio.wordpress.com/category/automssqlbackup/