# SMO.Restore.SqlRestore sometimes throws a timeout exception on deployed computers

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, smo

I have a app used for managing databases for demos of our software, one of the things that it does is get a copy of a database from a central server and restore it to a local SQL instance. Everything works correctly on the backup portion but on the restore some people are reporting that they get the following exception in the middle of the restore.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore failed for Server 'Computername'.
---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: 
     An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
     ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
          (snip)
          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
      (snip)
      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
at ContractFlowTool.WebInfinity2.AttachDatabase.RestoreLocal(AttachDatabaseArgs arg)
```

The [MSDN is fairly light](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.sqlrestore.aspx) on the inner working of the SMO classes. I could not find any method to change the timeout time for executing the restore. What can I do so the exception will not happen?

---

Here is the code performing the restore

```
private static bool RestoreLocal(AttachDatabaseArgs arg)
{
    if (arg.DestDatabase == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("DestDatabase");
    SqlConnectionInfo serverConnInfo = new SqlConnectionInfo(/*snip*/);
    ServerConnection serverConn = null;
    serverConn = new ServerConnection(serverConnInfo);
    var remoteServer = new Server(serverConn);
    var clinicFolder = ClinicFolder(arg);
    var restore = new Restore();
    restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 5;
    restore.NoRecovery = false;
    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(/*snip mdf*/);
    restore.RelocateFiles.Add(/*snip ldf*/);
    restore.Database = arg.LocalDB;
    restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restore.PercentComplete += arg.ProgressForm.Restore_PercentComplete;

    restore.SqlRestore(remoteServer);
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this personally? Is database size a factor? Are there any really huge binary fields that might be causing this? Does the timeout occur after a consistent time span? If you're really stuck, you might have a little luck digging into the actual assemblies using Reflector to see how they work (and replicating it, probably through reflection (to get at private/internal members), with a higher timeout). Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5979086/21475)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Camerons suggestion the solution to this issue was that I need to set `ServerConnection.StatementTimeout` higher. Apparently this happens frequently when databases are larger than 3GB.

```
(...) 
serverConn = new ServerConnection(serverConnInfo);
serverConn.StatementTimeout = 240; //<- set this.
var remoteServer = new Server(serverConn);
var clinicFolder = ClinicFolder(arg);
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

U could use this ,specially when you can't modify connection string or modification of timeout in connection string does not work
It works for me for a mirrored database over 2 GB

Using (SqlConnection1)

Dim sqlStmt As String = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE map TO DISK='{0}'", backup_directory + backupfile)

```
            Using bu2 As New SqlCommand(sqlStmt, SqlConnection1)
                SqlConnection1.Open()
                bu2.CommandTimeout = 180   //this line is the key
                bu2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                SqlConnection1.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Yes, StatementTimeout maps to CommandTimeout, however this question was about using SMO not SqlCommand