# Powershell restore script timing out

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Powershell script [based on this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110908/SQL-DB-Restore-using-PowerShell) that I've been using to automate my database restores, which has worked without a problem for a while now.

Recently it started failing and throwing timeout errors.

To highlight the code block from that example:

```
############################################################################
# Restore db Script block
############################################################################
[ScriptBlock] $global:RestoreDBSMO = {
    param([string] $newDBName, [string] $backupFilePath, [bool] $isNetworkPath = $true, [string] $newDataPath, [string] $newLogPath)
# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110908/SQL-DB-Restore-using-PowerShell
    try
    {
        # Load assemblies
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

        # Create sql server object
        $server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"

        # Copy database locally if backup file is on a network share
        if($isNetworkPath)
        {
            $fileName = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($backupFilePath)
            $localPath = Join-Path -Path $server.DefaultFile -ChildPath $fileName
            Copy-Item $backupFilePath $localPath
            $backupFilePath = $localPath
        }

        # Create restore object and specify its settings
        $smoRestore = new-object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore")
        $smoRestore.Database = $newDBName
        $smoRestore.NoRecovery = $false;
        $smoRestore.ReplaceDatabase = $true;
        $smoRestore.Action = "Database"

        # Create location to restore from
        $backupDevice = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceItem") ($backupFilePath, "File") 
        $smoRestore.Devices.Add($backupDevice)

        # Give empty string a nice name
        $empty = ""

        # Specify new data file (mdf)

           $smoRestoreDataFile = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile")
            if (($newDataPath -eq $null) -or ($newDataPath -eq $empty)) { #use exixting path
           $defaultData = $server.DefaultFile
            if (($defaultData -eq $null) -or ($defaultData -eq $empty))
            {
                $defaultData = $server.MasterDBPath
            }
        } Else {$defaultData = $newDataPath}
        $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $defaultData -ChildPath ($newDBName + "_Data.mdf")
        $smoRestoreDataFile.PhysicalFileName = $fullPath

        # Specify new log file (ldf)
        $smoRestoreLogFile = New-Object("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile")
        if (($newLogPath -eq $null) -or ($newLogPath -eq $empty)) { #use exixting path
            $defaultLog = $server.DefaultLog
            if (($defaultLog -eq $null) -or ($defaultLog -eq $empty))
            {
                $defaultLog = $server.MasterDBLogPath
            } 
        } Else {$defaultLog = $newLogPath}
        $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $defaultLog -ChildPath ($newDBName + "_Log.ldf")
        $smoRestoreLogFile.PhysicalFileName = $fullPath

        # Get the file list from backup file
        $dbFileList = $smoRestore.ReadFileList($server)

        # The logical file names should be the logical filename stored in the backup media
        $smoRestoreDataFile.LogicalFileName = $dbFileList.Select("Type = 'D'")[0].LogicalName
        $smoRestoreLogFile.LogicalFileName = $dbFileList.Select("Type = 'L'")[0].LogicalName

        # Add the new data and log files to relocate to
        $smoRestore.RelocateFiles.Add($smoRestoreDataFile)
        $smoRestore.RelocateFiles.Add($smoRestoreLogFile)

        # Restore the database
        $smoRestore.SqlRestore($server)

        "Database restore completed successfully"
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
        "Database restore failed:`n`n " + $_.Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        # Clean up copied backup file after restore completes successfully
        if($isNetworkPath)
        {
            Remove-Item $backupFilePath
        }
    }
}
```

When doing the actual restore, it throws the following error:

```
Restoring DB...
0
1
Database restore failed:

 Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore failed for Server 'SRV_MIC_DEV'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.
Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The backup or restore was aborted.
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
   at SqlRestore(Object , Object[] )
   at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
```

I've tried having a look over the Powershell documentation and other links and noticed that some websites mentioned that Powershell cmdlets have a 600 second default timeout.

I'm trying to find either a solution to **increase this timeout** from Powershell or from SQL Server, but I'm not really having any luck with documentation or regular web-searches.

Is there any quick fix for my script to increase the timeout or a simple alternative?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you using invoke-sqlcmd command in your script?

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan I've just googled `invoke-sqlcmd` and now I think I made some confusion about what a `cmdlet` is. I'm not using `invoke-sqlcmd` in my Powershell script, so I guess my problem is not the default 600 second timeout. But it's still a timeout problem. Do you know of any solutions to extend this?

Comment: if you are using invoke-sqlcmd in your script, then by default it will take timeout of 600 second. Because invoke-sqlcmd is an inbuilt command which comes as part of SQLPS module. if that is the condition i can provide you a function in which you can change the timeout value

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan Actually, I'm using the [**`SqlRestore`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.sqlrestore.aspx) method to do the actual restore of my DB. No SQL commands are being executed from my Powershell script. You can check the last line of code from my `try` block.

Comment: please post the full script used for restore if you don't mind

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan It's pretty much already posted at the beginning of my question, at least the relevant part. If I'd post the rest of the script there would be no value added, the rest of the script is calling some stored procedures in the restored DB, setting variable values etc.

Comment: I have saw the command invoke-sqlcmd in the link that was mentioned in the question. Just wanted to know whether it was also used in script

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan No, it isn't. I've searched for that in my script, just to make sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server timeout while restoring databases with SMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979086/sql-server-timeout-while-restoring-databases-with-smo)